# Get data from database between two dates using Google Charts asp.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, charts, google-visualization

I want to get data from database using two dates and get displayed in a chart.

I have used the link for the chart: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Charts-in-ASPNet-MVC-Google-Pie-Doughnut-Chart-example-with-database-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

I have used the following video for the dates and getting data from the database: https://youtu.be/Rm4uiny5Ano

```
     **CONTROLLER:** 

     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        mymodel db = new mymodel();
        db.slips = AjaxMethod();
        return View(db);
    }


        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        string query = "SELECT [status], sum(total_amount) as Payment";
        query += " FROM slips WHERE convert(varchar,date_paid, 101) BETWEEN '" + start + "' AND '" + end + "' and status='Paid' and inv_type='Valid' GROUP BY [status]";

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString;
        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                        "status", "Payment"
                        });
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                        sdr["status"], sdr["Payment"]
                        });
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return Json(chartData);
    }


     private DbSet<slip> AjaxMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
```

It should display data from a database using a chart. But then there's an error that it throws on the "AjaxMethod()" method. I don't know if my code on the "Index" it's correct.

[Chart Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbnBf.png)

Comment: Will you please share the error message? And if possible, a sample of the data...

Comment: @WhiteHat here is the error message: System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'  and the data should display a SUM total of Payment when selected the date range

Comment: I have managed to upload a picture and you may click the link "Chart Data" to view it.

Comment: The way this reads you are passing nothing `db.slips = AjaxMethod();` so it calls the `DbSet<slip> AjaxMethod()` method. which is exactly the message in your error.  What is your question?  (these two methods are not really a great pair with both the same name here...)

Comment: Note also that the `AjaxMethod(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)` passed no values will get null dates and the SQL will not return anything `BETWEEN` two null dates either. You really should pass date parameters to the SQL instead of stringing together a SQL statement.

Comment: Okay, I will check it. Tell me @MarkSchultheiss, is there a way I could pass date parameters to the SQL without using the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There is much more to this but just for your question and comment, you can create a `Payment` class and then a list of those and return that data.  This should all be in the proper files (per class) to do it right.

How you use this list of `payments` I will leave up to you  but you can start with this perhaps.  Your model for example might include the text for the column headers.

```
using PaymentRepository;

public ActionResult Index()
{
    PaymentModel db = new PaymentModel();
    // the model might also do this directly
    var chartData = PaymentRepository.GetPaidPaymentList();
    db.slips = chartData;
    return View(db);
}


[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetPaymentList(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
     var chartData = PaymentRepository.GetPaymentByStatusList(start,end);
     return Json(chartData); 
}

// put in a class with using Payment
public class PaymentRepository
{
    public static List<Payment> GetPaidPaymentList()
    {
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
        string status = "Paid";
        return GetPaymentByStatusList(startDate, endDate, status = );
    }

    public static List<Payment> GetPaymentByStatusList(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string status = "Paid")
    {
        List<Payment> payments = new List<Payment>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var sqlQuery = @"
            SELECT [status], SUM(total_amount) as Payment
            FROM slips 
            WHERE WHERE date_paid >= @startDate AND date_paid < @endDate 
                AND status = @status' 
                AND inv_type = 'Valid' 
            GROUP BY [status];
            ";
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters["@startDate"].Value = startDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters["@endDate"].Value = endDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = status;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var payment = new Payment()
                        {status = (string)reader["status"], payment = (decimal)reader["Payment"]};
                        payments.Add(payment);
                    }
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }

        return payments;
    }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string status
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public decimal payment
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```